# How to echo something to a .txt file even if it's executable as a program BATCH

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I have a BATCH script that will create a text file that will later be executed by another program based on user input. I want to be able to echo `Label>start` to a text file. Unfortunately, CMD reads it as a command (because of the > character) and does not echo properly. If I use quotation marks they echo to the .txt file

```
"Level>start"
```

and so it cannot be executed. I really need some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Level^>start
```

seems to work.